# trying to install grunt/browserify, npm install throws error looking for esprima-six as dependency of derequire

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, browserify, npm-install

I have a deprecated package set as a dependency somewhere, I believe as a global, and it keeps forcing errors when I try to install my modules. I first ran into it trying to get grunt and browserify installed locally in my project, running `npm install`. Here's what I get:

```
npm WARN deprecated react-tools@0.12.2: react-tools is deprecated. For more information, visit https://faebook.com/react-tools-deprecated
npm WARN deprecated native-buffer-browserify@2.0.17: Use the "buffer" module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) instead
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: esprima-six@~0.0.3
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'derequire'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/james/Code/play/isomorphic-react-example/npm-debug.log`
```

I've tried diagnosing and removing unneeded packages, but I keep running into that error no matter what I do.

Any suggestions?

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer via https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example/issues/26

The issue was isolated to the version of Broswerfy I was trying to install, which reference deprecated packages in its dependencies. The demo I was trying to run had an old version of Browserify (3.x.x) in its package.json. Upgrading to "^12.0.0" did the trick.